# probleme with Jtable in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have this two String

```
String[] columnNames
Object[][] data
```

i fill theme from database;
I have a `JComboBox` i want when i select item from the combobox and click `button` consuler, remove old `jtable` and repaint the new jtable with new `data`

here is the code of my `Jtable` that i put it inside the lister of `Jbutton` Consulter :

```
if(nbrC != 0){
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(62, 200, 457, 113);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);
    table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "pas d'horaire ds la BDD", "Erreur", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: what's the problem you are facing? Any issue/error/exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JComboBox i want when i select item from the combobox and click button consuler, remove old jtable and repaint the new jtable with new data

All you code does is create new Swing components, but you never actually add the components to the frame. Don't create new components.

The easier approach when you want to change the data in the table is to just reset the `TableModel` of the `JTable`.

So your code might be something like:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
table.setModel( model );
```

Now the TableModel will notify the JTable that changes to the data have been made and the table will repaint itself automatically.